# How do I find a subgroup $H$ of $S_3$ that is isomorphic with $G=A_3$ using the group left action method?

Tags: group-theory

I don't understand what I'm to do here very well. I started with defining the elements of $G$ as $e=$ identity, $x=(1 \, 2 \, 3)$ $y=(1 \, 3 \,2 )$ then left multiplying each element of $G$ successively with every element of $G$ under $\phi_g: G \to G$, $\phi_g(x)=gx$ to get H as:
 $$H=\{\phi_e, \phi_x, \phi_y\}.$$
Where $\phi_x=(e \, x \, y)$, $\phi_y=(e \, y \, x)$, and $\phi_e =$ identity. 
This doesn't seem right since I should be getting $H= A_3$, right?

Comment: Why do you think that $H\ne A_3$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Because I can't see how $x=\phi_x, y=\phi_y$. On the left side we have cycles, and on the right we have cycles of these cycles.

Comment: did you check $x=\phi_y$ and $y=\phi_x$

Comment: There is only one subgroup of $S_3$ of order 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as *Matt Samuel* pointed out, $A_{3}=\langle(123)\rangle$ is the only subgroup of order 3 of $S_{3}$. The other subgroups of $S_{3}$ are $\langle(12)\rangle,\langle(13)\rangle$ and $\langle(23)\rangle$, the trivial $1$ and $S_{3}$ itself. So, it is reasonable to get $H=A_{3}$ as *Hagen von Eitzen* noticed.

Now, let's show this by using group action by left multiplication. Let $A_{3}$ act on $\{1,2,3\}$ by left multiplication. For the identity element of $A_{3}$ we have the following permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$
$$\sigma_{1}(1)=1,\;\sigma_{1}(2)=2 \;\; \text{and} \;\; \sigma_{1}(3)=3$$ which means $\sigma_{1}=1$.
For $(123)$ we have
$$\sigma_{(123)}(1)=2,\; \sigma_{(123)}(2)=3 \;\; \text{and} \;\; \sigma_{(123)}(3)=1$$ which means $\sigma_{(123)}=(123)$.
Lastly, for $(132)$ we have
$$\sigma_{(132)}(1)=3, \; \sigma_{(132)}(2)=1 \;\; \text{and} \;\; \sigma_{(132)}(3)=2$$ which means $\sigma_{(132)}=(132)$.
Now we know that $A_{3}$ acts faithfully on $\{1,2,3\}$ by left multiplication, so the permutation representation $\phi:A_{3} \rightarrow S_{3}$, defined by $\phi(\tau)=\sigma_{\tau}, \forall \tau \in A_{3}$ is 1-1 and by the first Isomorphism Theorem we get $A_{3} \cong Im(\phi) \leq S_{3}$. But as you can see $Im(\phi)=A_{3}$. Thus, $H:= Im(\phi)=A_{3}$.

Notice that what we did is the same as if we let $A_{3}$ act on itselft by left multiplication and label the elements of $A_{3}$ with the integers 1,2,3 respectively.